# Kivy Spell Checker

Tags: python, kivy

I've been learning kivy with an iMac using Codemy Youtube tutorials and I'm currently up to implementing a spell checker app.  I've studied the code in the tutorial and I've written everything necessary for the project but when I run it and enter the word to be checked and press the button, I get an error stating 'TypeError: 'NoneType' is not callable.  From the looks of things it has to do with the imported Spelling on line 7 as when I hover over it, it's apparently a NoneType and I have no idea why as it's the first option from the menu when specify 'from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling'. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Here are the py and kv files.

spell_checker.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling

Builder.load_file('spell_checker.kv')

class SpellCheckerLayout(Widget):
    def press(self):
        #Create instance of spelling
        s = Spelling()

        #Select the language
        s.select_language('en_US')

        #See language options
        print(s.list_languages())

        #Grab word from text box
        word = self.ids.word_input.text
    
        option = s.suggest(word)

        #Update our label
        self.ids.word_label.text = f'{option}' 


class BackgroundApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return SpellCheckerLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BackgroundApp().run()
```

spell_checker.kv

```
<SpellCheckerLayout>
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.width, root.height
    
    Label:
        id: word_label
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        text: "Enter A Word"
        font_size: 32

    TextInput:
        id: word_input
        multiline: False
        size_hint: (1, .5)

    Button:
        size_hint: (1, .5)
        font_size: 32
        text: "Submit"
        on_press: root.press()
```

Comment: Check out log file to find whether there is any spelling provider or not.

Comment: You need the module "python-enchant". Make sure you have it installed. I tested your code and got no problem, so that must be.

Comment: That was issue thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue happen since I was using python 3.10. I tried running it with python 3.6 and it worked, so if you are running it in a newer version try going to an older version of python like 3.6.